# PHP: Display complete value of a column from one table to other table on next page when checked

Tags: php, html

This is working well. The only problem is that if a row has the value "hello world" in a column of the item on the first page, it shows only "hello" in the item column on second page. I want it to show the complete value "hello world" in next page table. Any suggestions?

First page code:

```
`<?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bhaiya_pizza");
        if($conn-> connect_error){
            die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
        }
        $sql="SELECT id,item,price from beverages";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $values = $row["id"].'|'.$row["price"].'|'.$row["item"];
            echo"<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."</td> 
            <td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>"."<input type='checkbox' 
            name='menu[]' 
            value=".$values."></td></tr>"; 
        }
        echo"</table>"; }else {
        echo"0 result"; }
        $conn->close();
?>`
```

Second page code:

```
`<table  border="2px" align="center">
<tr >
    <th width="100">ID</th> 
    <th width="200">Item</th>
    <th width="100">Price</th>
</tr>
<?php 
    $name=$_POST['menu'];
    foreach ($name as $row) {
        $values = explode("|",$row);
        echo"<tr><td>".$values[0]."</td><td>".$values[2]."</td> 
        <td>".$values[1]."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
</table>`
```

Comment: you do print_r($values);  & let me know?

Comment: i did not use print_r($values);

Comment: where to use print_r($values); on first or second page

Comment: it's not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have space in word, and HTML think that this is next attribute of input tag.
I suggest you to encode your data in json and base64:

At first page, instead of your $values string, create an array and encode it:

```
$btn_values = [
    $row["id"],
    $row["price"],
    $row["item"],
];
$values = base64_encode(json_encode($btn_values));
echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>"."<input type='checkbox'
        name='menu[]'
        value=".$values."></td></tr>";
```

At second page do the reverse operation:

```
$values = json_decode(base64_decode($row));

echo "<tr><td>".$values[0]."</td><td>".$values[2]."</td>
    <td>".$values[1]."</td></tr>";
```

Your string will have no any special chars (that can prevent of normal displaying of table):

```
WzEsMS45OSwiaGVsbG8gd29ybGQiXQ==
```